# How do make sure 'Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 1 Object Model' has been installed using InstallShield LE in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installshield, installshield-le

I am deploying a project that requires 'Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 1 Object Model' to be installed on the users computer before it continues with the installation.

I am trying to accomplish this on the Installation Requirements tab by creating a custom software condition.  I can't seem to find a unique way of detecting if it is installed or not.  Which should I use?

- File path, by searching folders
- Folder path, by searching all drives
- Folder path, by searching in a specific folder
- Folder path, by searching for a specific file
- File path, as specified by a registry entry
- Folder path, as specified by a registry entry
- Registry entry
- File path, as specified by an .ini file value
- Folder path, as specified by an .ini file value
- .ini file value

And, what do I use for the values?